# Schema design for marketplace

Tags: mysql, schema

We are creating a marketplace where users can create certain tasks and other users will be able to do it (like fiverr). Our current schema is like this

```
 - TasksTable (TaskId, UserId, Rate, CountryAllowed)
 - TasksCompletedTable (Id, TaskId , UserId, Rate)
 - UserId (UserId, Country)
```

This is working perfectly but now we want to revise this because a user who creates a task should be able to create a task with Rate per country so the users who will be performing the tasks will be rewarded based on the rate of their country set by the advertiser.
We can create a weak entity with only 4 columns `Id, TaskId, Country, Rate` but usually any task would be allowed for all countries so there would be 250+ rows for each task. Another approach would be to create `JSON` of each task and store it in the Tasks table. Something like

[    {"Country":"Rate"},{"Country":"Rate"}]

The reason to do this is we need to order by Rate all tasks sometimes to display to the user. I am still researching what would the best approach to do this in terms of performance and scalability.

Comment: _"Another approach would be to create JSON of each task and store it in the Tasks table"_ <-- This is not an approach worth considering: you'll drown in technical-debt. (Also, why JSON? There are plenty of superior ways of packing structured data into a database column with DBMS support, like T-SQL'`s `xml` and Postgres' `array` types).

Comment: I am open to suggestions.